# How to get git tags on all clones of repository?

Tags: git

I have a git repository set up that looks something like this:

```
          PROD
         /
BARE_REPO — TEST
        \
         DEV
```

I do all my development on dev (obviously). This is also where I create my tags. When something is ready to go to our TEST environment I do a `git tag -a 03/01/201a` and then a `git push`. Then I ssh into TEST and perform a `git pull`.

If I type `git tag` on dev it lists a bunch of tags whereas if I do a `git tag` on TEST or PROD it only shows my very first tag. Apparently `git add .` does not add tags to be committed and pushed. I want all three environments to share tags so that if something goes wonky in PROD or TEST I can simply roll back to the previous tag.

Any help on "pushing" tags (if that's even a thing)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `git push --tags` to push tags.